# Slicing numpy.ndarray by column index

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to slice the array below without having to define the row indices i.e. not having to write `range(len(X))`?

```
X = np.arange(10*2).reshape((10,2))
L = np.random.randint(0,2,10)

Xs = X[range(len(X)),L]
```

I thought it was possible to slice with `X[:,L]` but looks like it's not.

Comment: My `linspace` takes two arguments minimum: start and end.  So your code doesn't run.  Is your NumPy different?  What version?  Also, `X[:,L]` does work for me, provided that I do `linspace(5, 20, 10*2)` or so.

Comment: No, you can't. Though you should use `np.arange()` instead of `range()`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @JohnZwinck: my mistake it was supposed to be np.arange and not np.linspace.

Comment: `L` has shape `(10,)`, but you're using it to index the dimension of `X` that has length 2, not the length 10 one. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Evert: yes, it's intentional. I want to select one element of X[i] based on the value of L[i]

Comment: Did you mean `X[:, L].diagonal()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [np.choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
In [25]: X = np.arange(10*2).reshape((10,2)); X
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])

In [26]: L = np.random.randint(0,2,10); L
Out[26]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

In [27]: L.choose(X.T)
Out[27]: array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19])

In [28]: # or otherwise

In [29]: np.choose(L, X.T)
Out[29]: array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19])
```

**Performance note**: while this solution is a direct answer to the question, it's quickly becomes not the most optimal with increase of `len(X)`. As of numpy 1.9.0, `np.arange` approach is faster:

```
In [17]: %timeit X[range(len(X)), L]
1000 loops, best of 3: 629 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit X[np.arange(len(X)), L]
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.8 µs per loop

In [19]: %timeit L.choose(X.T)
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop

In [20]: X.shape, L.shape
Out[20]: ((10000, 2), (10000,))
```

Comment: Yes!  This is the one I was trying to work out earlier but didn't get the transpose right so it didn't work.  This looks like the best solution so far.

Comment: Does this solution have any advantage over mine with range(...)?

Comment: @memecs, it doesn't create an intermediate array, BUT it seems to get slower faster than a solution using `np.arange` when increasing `len(L)`.

Answer (score 1):

You take the diagonal elements of `X[:,L]` using [`diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) (or [`diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)):

```
np.diag(X[:,L])
```

Another way to do it is with [`where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(L,X[:,1],X[:,0])
```

Comment: This seems to work but is a bit unsatisfying because it constructs a temporary which is len(L)^2 in size--and `diag()` may end up returning a view depending on some details, so that N^2 memory usage may stick around for the life of the result unless you explicitly copy it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I added an alternative which, I think - please correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't construct a len(L)^2 temporary, or cause similar memory issues.

Comment: Right, the version using `where` is more efficient for large inputs I think.  But it's a bit unsatisfying also, because it doesn't generalize to more than two columns in `X`.  Oh well, it works for the OP's stated case.  By the way you can just use `L` instead of `L==1`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck. I agree. Also, I included your tip re `L`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
In [9]: X[:, L]
Out[9]:
array([[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
   [ 3,  3,  2,  2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  3,  2],
   [ 5,  5,  4,  4,  5,  4,  5,  4,  5,  4],
   [ 7,  7,  6,  6,  7,  6,  7,  6,  7,  6],
   [ 9,  9,  8,  8,  9,  8,  9,  8,  9,  8],
   [11, 11, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10],
   [13, 13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12],
   [15, 15, 14, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14],
   [17, 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16],
   [19, 19, 18, 18, 19, 18, 19, 18, 19, 18]])
```

And you want the diagonal elements:

So just do:

```
In [14]: X[:, L].diagonal()
Out[14]: array([ 1,  3,  4,  6,  9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18])
```

Comment: As commented already in another answer, creating an N^2 matrix is rather inefficient.